# HighChart - Stacked Bar chart - To show dash line over the bar chart to the specific portion in the bar

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

[image]I tried to highlight specific portion in the bar chart like above screenshot. Whenever we tried to highlight, it always from the origin of the y axis. It would be great if you have to possible solution to achieve this use cases. Attached screenshot the way solution expecting.

Code Snippet:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan'],
    visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    visible: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [{
      y: 15
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [{
      y: 22
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'red',
    zIndex: 1000,
    data: [
   { x:0,y:44}]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to color the border of another series. So instead of:

```
series: [..., {
 name: 'Joe',
 borderWidth: 3,
 borderColor: 'red',
 zIndex: 1000,
 data: [
  { x:0,y:44}]
}]
```

you can write:

```
series: [..., {
 name: 'Jane',
 borderWidth: 2,
 borderColor: 'red',
 zIndex: 1,     
 data: [{
  y: 22
}]
}, ...]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/648ef3v7/